# Having alignment issue in forms with bootstrap twitter

Tags: forms, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I have a form with a input type and a button type here

```
<div class="span12" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 5px;">
    <div class="row-fluid mt20">
        <div id="searchBox">
        <form id="general-search-form" autocomplete="off">
            <input type="text" placeholder="" class="search-query" name="q" />
                <button type="submit" class="btn pull-right" title="search"></button>
        </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to have the layout such that in the desktop version the input type occupies 50 percent width and the search button occupies 50 percent width. In mobile version the input type should be at top and the search button should be at below. How to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your probably want to have something like this...

```
<form>
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span6">
   <input type="text" class="input-block-level">
  </div>
  <div class="span6">
   <button type="submit" class="btn custom-button">Search</button>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Then you would need to style the button yourself to make it take up the full width of the span6.

```
.custom-button {
    width: 100%;
}
```

You'll probably need some trial and error with the button width taking into account padding & borders.

Answer (score 0):

Set `float:left` to both elements in browser CSS with width set to 50%.
For mobile device CSS use `float:none`. Try to make width 100%.

This will give you required output. There may or may not be a small tweaking needed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is there anyway to do it using spans?

Comment: Why do you want it with spans. Spans are for inline elements. Your form elements are not inline elements.

Comment: @HarpreetK. - I think he's talking about spans in relation to Bootstrap. span1, span2, span3 etc are classes in Bootstrap which are part of its grid system.